# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel: Slides All Showing Simultaneously

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to just get the example carousel code from the Bootstrap guide to work on my homepage, and for some reason, my homepage ends up displaying all the homepage contents once on the top (with the left and right arrows) and all the homepage contents again right under it (also with the left and right arrows). Clicking on the left arrow and right arrow just scrolls me to the top contents and to the bottom contents.

I've included bootstrap.js and jquery.js, in that order. Any ideas on what could be going wrong? Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner"> 
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
       </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
        <img class="banner" src="/images/dataimage.jpg">
</div>
<div class="container wrapper">
    <div class="jumbotron   ">
        <h1>moocRP</h1>

        <h2>...under development</h2>
        <a href="/user/login" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Login now!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've included bootstrap.js and jquery.js, in that order.

Try the other way around :)

Comment: Then something must not point correctly. Open the Developer Tools (F12) and check which file is not getting loaded.

Comment: The relevant files seem to be loaded (jQuery and Bootstrap javascript files). No reference errors show up.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing a div class="container" .

```
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner"> 
<div class="item active">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
   <div class="container"> <!--THIS ONE-->
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
   </div>
</div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Why do I need a container there?

Comment: I think that this is the standar code for the carousel.Any way if that didn't work make sure to locate your stylesheet files below  bootstrap.css  style file. Than  browsers will apply modyfined properties and overwrite Bootstrap properties by default.

Comment: Doing that doesn't work; nothing should be overwriting the stylesheets as they are the last stylesheets to be linked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what is your problem. The code you've posted is working properly
There are no errors on left and right arrow

```
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
```

I've used the ff: jQuery 1.9.1 Bootstrap.js, Bootstrap.css
Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/programmer101/j9bPF/

Answer (score 0):

Check each item div doesn't also have the 'active' class applied to it!

I copied the first slide with it on a was puzzled why the slides repeating on top of each other.

:)